# Infinite coin tosses- same number of heads and tails will occur infinitely many times

Tags: probability, borel-cantelli-lemmas

Dear math stack exchange community,

It's my first post, so hello and please let me know if I haven't posted this question in a proper way- happy to edit it.

**So here's an exercise which I'm trying to solve:**

We are tossing a fair coin infinitely many times.
Let $A_n$ be an event that in first $n$ tosses we had same number of heads and tails.
Show that with Probability 1 events $A_n$ will occur for infinitely many values of $n$.

This is an exercise from Borel-Cantelli Lemma's chapter, so I assume I should use it somehow to prove it.

**What I already know:**

For each $n \in \mathbb{N}:$

$P(A_{2n+1}) = 0$

$P(A_{2n}) = \binom{2n}{n}p^n(1-p)^n$ (in our case $p = 1/2$)

But I cannot use those events in order to show divergence of series of those probabilities, because they are not independent and assumption for B-C Lemma will not apply.

I believe I should construct independent events somehow, but here's where I am stuck- I have no clue how to do it.

Any hints on that? Just in case it's rather expected to do it without prior knowledge about random walks, but any hints/answers are very welcome.

Thank you a lot!

Comment: If we toss a coin infinitely many times, the first $n$ tosses occur exactly once for any given $n.$ So no matter what value of $n$ we choose, $A_n$ can occur at most once. Did you try to paraphrase the problem from the wording in which it was originally presented?

Comment: In the meantime I realised bad wording and tried to paraphrase already- now it states "infinitely many of $A_n$ events will occur". Is that clear now? Unfortunately I don't have this question in English so I'm trying to translate it.

Comment: Do you mean to say "for infinitely many values of $n$"?

Comment: Yes, thank you.

Comment: Now I understand what you mean in "what I already know". I hope someone has a better idea what to do next.

Comment: I edited it again using your wording so it should be easier to understand now.

Comment: Seems like it might be enough to show that the #H - #T returns to 0 (just once) with probability $1$, since then you start over from there, so to speak.

Answer (score 1):

Let $p_k$ denote the probability that the number of heads and tails will ever equalize when there is an excess of $k$ in either direction. By first-step analysis, we have

$$
p_k=\frac12(p_{k-1}+p_{k+1})\;.
$$

This is the discretized Laplace equation in one dimension, and the solutions are exactly the linear functions. Since a non-constant linear function eventually leaves the admissible range $[0,1]$ of probabilities, it follows that $p_k$ is constant. Then the boundary condition $p_0=1$ implies that $p_k=1$ for all $k$.

Since the probability for at least one equalization is $1$, the probability for at least $m$ equalizations is $1$ for all $m\in\mathbb N$. Thus the probability for  exactly $m$ equalizations is $0$ for all $m\in\mathbb N_0$. By countable additivity, the probability of the union of these events for all $m\in\mathbb N_0$ is also $0$. Thus the probability of its complement, the event that there are infinitely many equalizations, is $1$.